# ngx_cookie_1 is not defined

Tags: angular, angular-cookies

sorry for probably wrong form, but this is my first post. I couldn't find solution for my error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ngx_cookie_service_1 is not defined
>      at eval (super.service.ts:39)
>      at eval (super.service.ts:287)
>      at Object../src/app/services/super-service/super.service.ts (main.bundle.js:624)
>      at **webpack_require** (inline.bundle.js:55)
>      at eval (profile.service.ts:2)
>      at Object../src/app/services/profile/profile.service.ts (main.bundle.js:608)
>      at **webpack_require** (inline.bundle.js:55)
>      at eval (app.module.ts:52)
>      at Object../src/app/app.module.ts (main.bundle.js:43)
>      at **webpack_require** (inline.bundle.js:55)

I used 'ngx-cookie-service' in my old project and everything worked fine.

In my app.module I've imported it as it should be.

```
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';



providers: [
    CookieService,
  [...]
]
```

and added field to service's constructor

```
constructor(
    protected cookieService: CookieService,
    [...]
) { }
```

Does anyone know what is the cause and how to eliminate it?

Comment: did u install the npm package

Comment: I did several times. I even used 'ngx-cookie' module and everything looked exacly the same except of name (Uncaught ReferenceError: ngx_cookie_1 is not defined at eval [...])